# iOS. Communicating with Other Applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, ipad, ios

Is it possible to communicate with other applications in iOS, I mean:

- tracking time of other applications in foreground
- have access to resources (for example can I determine which books exist in iBooks)
- can we determine is specified app installed on device

?

Answer (score 0):

Much of this is possible, but none is possible with official APIs and you will thus not get your app approved by Apple if you tried these things.

Comment: Ok, thnks. Is official API exists for time tracking of other apps in foreground?